# Finding segments in Praat textgrids

Tags: phonetics, praat

I need to find the second to last segment in a segment tier (1) within a word on the word tier (3). So far, I have:

```
# Find the word in the word tier
n = Get number of intervals: 3
for i to n
  label$ = Get label of interval: 3, i
  if label$ == ‘.word$’
    index = i
    i += n
  endif
endfor

# get the start and end point of that word
startingpoint = Get starting point... 3 index
endpoint = Get end point... 3 index
```

and then I'm not sure how to limit the search to just the word I found previously. The easiest way to approach this, I think, is if there was some way to count the intervals on tier 1 *within* the word boundary get the information from the total number of intervals - 1.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have found a way to do what I want by adding this to the above script:

```
 # get the last_segment interval number
 last_segment = Get low interval at time: 1, endpoint
 penult_segment = last_segment - 1

 # get vowel label and start and end
 vowellabel$ = Get label of interval: 1, penult_segment

 # get the start time and end time of the interval
 vowelstart = Get starting point... 1 penult_segment
 vowelend = Get end point... 1 penult_segment
```